# Flawed "or logic" in onButtonClick causing force close

Tags: java, android, logical-operators

I'm stuck with the last thing for my app. When the button bSubmit is pressed, all the functions work except that app is force closing when no input is given in the EditText boxes, instead of force closing, I tried to put a toast msg, which doesn't work either. I suppose there's a flaw in my logic

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.bSubmit) {

        String numstr = numberEditText.getText().toString();
        String pontstr = pointEditText.getText().toString();
        int point = Integer.parseInt(pontstr);
        //takes in the customer's number and the purchase amount

        //search for the customer's number in database
        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        Log.d("onButtonClick",""+numstr);
        customer = helper.searchCustomer(numstr);



        if (numstr.equals(null) || pontstr.equals(null)){
            Context toastcontext = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text ="You haven't put any value";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;


            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(toastcontext,text, duration);
            toast.show();

        }



        if (customer.getuNum() != null && customer.getuNum().equals(numstr)) {

            //if found then add the amount as new points
            //int row = helper.searchRow(customer.getuNum());
           // int point = helper.searchPoint(customer.getuNum());
            int pnt =  customer.getPoint() + point;
            Log.d("MainActivity",customer.getuNum()+" pnt "+pnt);
            helper.updatePoint(pnt,customer.getuNum());
            currentPoint.setText("Your point is "+pnt);
        }

        else {

            //create a new customer and add the info to database
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setuNum(numstr);
            customer.setPoint(point);
            helper.insertCustomer(customer);
            Log.d("MainActivity","customer null num "+customer.getuNum()+" point "+point);
            currentPoint.setText("Your point is " + point);
        }

        numberEditText.getText().clear();
        pointEditText.getText().clear();
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the logs of fatal ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AW2ZDiZmvKgFqYroQWoAKUziwYd-UL4VM0S-iVR4g5g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

`int point = Integer.parseInt(pontstr);` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the input is not an Integer (in the case of it being an empty String  `""` when nothing is in the EditText, or anything but an Integer value). This would cause the silent crash that you're talking about.

My advice would be to surround your `parseInt()` call with a try-catch block, and handle the case where the call would throw a NumberFormatException. Something like this:

`int example;
    try {
        example = Integer.parseInt(pontstr);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Logic to deal with invalid input, maybe toast the user.
    }`

Comment: No, that's not the issue. Even if I don't use the logic OR logic or that IF logic at all, my app is forcely closed when nothing is inputted. I just need a toast to show that nothing is given

Comment: from your logs it is clear that you are getting number format exception : Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: I believe that your comment was intended for the other answer (although he gives a valid point as well; You should check for empty strings as he is doing). My answer is talking about the `int point = Integer.parseInt(pontstr);`, before any of your if statements.

Comment: I'm a noob, I'm very confused right now :( I don't understand

Comment: We all started there lol, I'll try to explain it better.

The `parseInt()` call throws an Exception. Since you aren't dealing with this Exception, the program has nowhere to go and therefore stops executing. 

In Java, you can deal with Exceptions by *catching* them, like this:
`try {
    Integer.parseInt(pontstr);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   // Logic to deal with invalid input, maybe toast the user.
}`

Comment: Can you tell me how to handle the integer?

Comment: Thanks bro, I'll study about it a little bit more and get back to you :)

Comment: No problem. [This link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) can give you some more information on Java Exceptions to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

1. You will get number format exception if your string is not a number. You need to put the statement after your empty checks are passed.
2. You are checking in wrong way .

   if (numstr.trim().isEmpty() || pontstr.trim().isEmpty(){
               Context toastcontext = getApplicationContext();
               CharSequence text ="You haven't put any value";
               int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

   ```
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(toastcontext,text, duration);
           toast.show();

       }
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping man but it still isn't working. I don't understand why